# Why would SQS fail to set a VisibilityTimeout of 43199 when the max is stated as 43200?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Recently needed to set some really long timeouts on SQS messages and saw that the documented limit was 12 hours (43200). So I tried setting the timeout to 1s under that and got this error back that sounds crazy (in that 43199 is in fact less than 43200 in most number systems).

`SQSError: SQSError: 400 Bad Request
SenderInvalidParameterValueValue 43199 for parameter VisibilityTimeout is invalid. Reason: Total VisibilityTimeout for the message is beyond the limit [43200 seconds]`

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Looks like it was the concept of 'Total' timeout being different from what the timeout I was setting with the change_visibility API call. The Total is ticking from when the message was first received

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you were setting message visibility with `ChangeMessageVisibility` API on message which were already received at that moment and not visible.

Visibility timeout is 12 hour for message in **total**. It means that when you receive message, visibility timeout is already running for this message. When you call `ChangeMessageVisibility` you can increase visibility timeout only with value which will not breach 12 hours in total with already elapsed visibility timeout.

Comment: It looks like this 'total' concept is indeed the culprit, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: These seems totally* unclear from the SQS doc (at least to me). It read like you could add up to 12 hours at any point. *pun intended.

Comment: Another limitation of AWS. Crap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting error if you specify the value as 43199 but I just tried to create a queue in AWS Console with 12 hours as the Default Visibility timeout.

[image: AWS Console]

**Edit :**

I tried to set the visibility timeout via. CLI as 43199 seconds and it succeeded as well - I think it must be an interim issue, please try again.

```
aws sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/12345677/test --attributes VisibilityTimeout=43199
```

[image: CLI AWS SQS]